# Can I use OR in css and jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to use an `OR` or `||` when selecting something in css and jQuery?

Instead of: `$('body.mod div, body.edit div').on('click'...`

You would write something like:

`$('body.mod||body.edit div').on('click'...`

And with css something like: `body.mod||body.edit div {}`

Comment: _"Is it possible to ..."_ <- no

Comment: You dont need it ... just separate selectors with comma , like  SelA, SelB. Or does not make sense because its this or that. https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: You could always use `find()`, eg `$('body.mod, body.edit').find('div')` or event delegation, eg `$('body.mod, body.edit').on('click', 'div', ...)`

Comment: @daremachine Not really. Only the first part is different the div is the same for both. It's the div I don't want to re-type. This is a simple example but if it was longer than just a `div` it would make more sense with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Phil Thanks! Would that event delegation work with `$(document).on` as well? I assume I'd run out of "slots" at that point.

Comment: Event delegation makes the most sense here. There actually _is_ a possibility, using [`:matches` or `:any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:matches).

Comment: Yes but your posted example dont need or because you can specify exact selector. IMHO

Comment: I don't know what a _"slot"_ is in this context but yes, you can listen for events at the `document` level and use a selector for delegation

Comment: @Phil I mean something like `$(document).on('click', 'body.mod, body.edit', 'div', ...)`

Comment: @SeaBass no. I suggest you read the jQuery API documentation next time